# Migrate an UCMA 3 application on a Lync 2013 architecture

Tags: ucma, lync-2013, lync-server-2010, ucwa

I have a currently working UCMA 3.0 application running on an Lync 2010 application server and registered to a Lync 2010 front end server. I need to deploy it on a new Lync 2013 architecture. My application is quite simple, it just returns the precense status of a user. I've a webservice for accessing to it.

I found this article: [here](http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/10/16/ucma-3-0-lync-server-2013/)

And I see 3 ways to do it:

- **Use UCMA 3.0 on a Lync 2013 architecture:**
  In that case I need to install a Lync server 2010 and UCMA 3 on an application server, and to register my application pool to a Lync 2013 front end. Is that OK? Do you think that this solution can work as well as an UCMA 4 solution?
- **Migrate my UCMA 3.0 application into a UCMA 4.0 application:**
  Do I just need to recompile my application with a UCMA 4 SDK? Do you know if there is  a lot of changes between this two versions?
- **Re develop My application into an UCWA application:**
  I've heard of UCWA wich provides precence capabilitites too. And it seems to be pretty simple to develop, deploy and maybe maintain in the future.

Wich one is the best solution for you?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take from experience:-

- I've not done this as the additional required resources usually isn't an option, although I imagine it'll work fine.
- I have done this in the past, it has just been a case of including reference to UCMA 4 and changing the .net version.
- UCWA is more of a client end SDK and depending on what your current
  UCMA does it may not be suitable.